# What's the opposite of `unpack("m")`?

Tags: ruby, encoding, base64

I'm trying to figure out how to encode a session cookie in a similar fashion to that of [Facebook's signed_request](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/signed_request/).

The [runwithfriends Facebook sample app](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/samples/canvas/) [implements base64_url_decode & base64_url_decode in Python](https://github.com/facebook/runwithfriends/blob/master/main.py#L182).

I've found a simple implementation of `base64_url_decode`:

```
def base64_url_decode(string)
  "#{string}==".tr("-_", "+/").unpack("m")[0]
end
```

How do I implement `base64_url_encode` w/o `require 'base64'`. (I figure it's better to do it w/o `require 'base64'`, right?)

Basically, what's the opposite of `unpack("m")`?

```
ruby-1.9.2-p0 > "aGVsbG8sIG1ycyB0ZWFs\012".unpack("m")
 => ["hello, mrs teal"]
```

Answer (score 3):

Viewing the source of `Base64.encode64` from [the documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/base64/rdoc/classes/Base64.html#M000003) yields:

```
# File base64.rb, line 37
def encode64(bin)
  [bin].pack("m")
end
```

Yes, the opposite of `unpack` is [`pack`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Array.html#M000206).

Comment: The most obvious ask/answer on SO, that I ever saw ..D But no, another was *what is [[]] in Ruby?*

Comment: Oh! Haha. Thanks! I was looking for Sting#pack.

Comment: Worked! Now, how do I do `rstrip('=')` (which they're doing in Python) in Ruby?

Comment: @MattDiPasquale I can understand your confusion, though it's not entirely nonsensible given that `String#unpack => Array` and `Array#pack => String`. Anyhow, assuming I am understanding `rstrip` correctly, `str.rstrip('abc')` in Python is equivalent to `str.sub( /[abc]+$/, '' )` in Ruby. So: `without_trailing_equals = str.sub( /=+$/, '' )`

Comment: @Phrogz, thanks! I thought there might've been a built in method, I was going to use `gsub`, but `sub` is better since I only want to replace one occurrence, not all. And now, I finally understand the difference between `sub` & `gsub`. It's like the `g` flag in vim or sed. Nice! Thank you!

Comment: @MattDiPasquale, [`.chomp('=')`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/String.html#M001188)

Comment: @Nakiton, oh, that's it! I had a feeling there was something like that. Thanks!

Comment: @Nakilon is dead-on with his answer for your use case, but note that Ruby's `String#chomp` is not equivalent to Python's `rstrip` in the general case.

Comment: Although, @Phrogz, your solution, using [`sub!`](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/trunk/string.c#L3544), is almost 3 times faster than that of @Nakiton, using [`chomp!`](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/trunk/string.c#L6168). I guess `sub!` is implemented more efficiently. Should I sacrifice speed for readability? :)

Answer (score 1):

> > what's the opposite of unpack("m")?

Surely it's `pack("m")`? Or is this a trick question?

```
["hello, mrs teal"].pack("m") # => "aGVsbG8sIG1ycyB0ZWFs\n"
```

Comment: I suppose problem was in that questioner forgot to add `[]`.